# GCM Playground - Couldn't connect to Docker daemon

Tags: android, docker, google-cloud-messaging, daemon

I'm trying to execute sample application server for Google Cloud Messaging on the github.
https://github.com/googlesamples/gcm-playground

I followed their instruction as follows.

```
1. Install Docker, Docker Compose, and if using on a Mac Docker Machine.

2.Install Node.js >=0.12.0.

3.Clone this repo.

4.$ ./start.sh
```

However, after the fourth step, it shown error.

[image]

GCM app server is working on docker?

should I make a docker machine for the server?

Answer (score 0):

update last line of start.sh with `sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: I have the same problem, and tried with sudo, but the command is not recognizes. I am getting: ./start.sh: line 53: sudo: command not found